# mod_rewrite sending incorrect results

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

My rewrite rule is the following:

`RewriteRule ^groups/([0-9]+)/pg:([0-9]+);cr:(0|1);r:([a-z0-9-]+);rv:(0|1);eu:(0|1);fr:(0|1);de:(0|1);it:(0|1);ru:(0|1);es:(0|1);br:(0|1);la:(0|1);us:(0|1);au:(0|1)$ index.php?mod=groups&groups=$1&pg=$2&crossrealm=$3&realm=$4&reverse=$5&eu=$6&fr=$7&de=$8&it=$9&ru=$10&es=$11&br=$12&la=$13&us=$14&au=$15 [NC,L]`

Which does the redirection successfully, however, the `$_GET` sent displays incorrect results:

```
$_GET:
array (size=16)
  'mod' => string 'groups' (length=6)
  'groups' => string '117' (length=3)
  'pg' => string '1' (length=1)
  'crossrealm' => string '1' (length=1)
  'realm' => string 'aegwynn' (length=7)
  'reverse' => string '0' (length=1)
  'eu' => string '1' (length=1)
  'fr' => string '0' (length=1)
  'de' => string '0' (length=1)
  'it' => string '0' (length=1)
  'ru' => string '1170' (length=4)
  'es' => string '1171' (length=4)
  'br' => string '1172' (length=4)
  'la' => string '1173' (length=4)
  'us' => string '1174' (length=4)
  'au' => string '1175' (length=4)
```

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this issue and how it can be fixed?

`EDIT`: The errors begin with the mod_rewrite part which starts at `$10`, i.e. `&ru=`. The rewritten URL returns correctly yet the actual one is `http://localhost/index.php?mod=groups&groups=117&pg=1&crossrealm=1&realm=aegwynn&reverse=0&eu=1&fr=0&de=0&it=1&ru=1170&es=1171&br=1172&la=1173&us=1174&au=1175`

Comment: How does your http call look like?

Comment: Sorry for being ignorant, but could you tell me how can I check this? This is a field I do not have a lot of knowledge in.

Comment: Sure, in other words: Whats the URL in your browser pointing to this script?

Comment: `http://localhost/groups/117/pg:1;cr:1;r:aegwynn;rv:0;eu:1;fr:0;de:0;it:0;ru:1;es:1;br:0;la:0;us:0;au:0`, just as it should be redirected, otherwise a 404 page would be shown.

Comment: Try replacing temporarily `[NC,L]` with `[NC,L,R]` so you can **see** the redirected URL.

Comment: @faa it's ~`mod=groups&groups=73&pg=1&crossrealm=1&realm=aegwynn&reverse=0&eu=1&fr=0&de=0&it=0&ru=730&es=731&br=732&la=733&us=734&au=735` now

Comment: Post the `~` part too. The whole URL you see.

Comment: @faa It's `http://localhost/D:/dev/Websites/DefaultWebsite/webroot/index.php?mod=groups&groups=117&pg=1&crossrealm=1&realm=aegwynn&reverse=0&eu=1&fr=0&de=0&it=1&ru=1170&es=1171&br=1172&la=1173&us=1174&au=1175`, removing the disc part becoming `http://localhost/index.php?mod=groups&groups=117&pg=1&crossrealm=1&realm=aegwynn&reverse=0&eu=1&fr=0&de=0&it=1&ru=1170&es=1171&br=1172&la=1173&us=1174&au=1175`

Comment: Added some extra details to the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mod-rewrite` doesn't allow you to catch more than 9 parameters (from `$1` to `$9`).

In your case, `$10` is readen as `($1)0`, that's why you got '1170'.

You should better send the entire requested URI and explode it with PHP :

```
  list(
    $_GET['mod'], 
    $_GET['groups'], 
    $_GET['pg'], 
    $_GET['crossrealm'], 
    $_GET['realm'], 
    $_GET['reverse'], 
    $_GET['eu'], 
    $_GET['fr'], 
    $_GET['de'], 
    $_GET['it'], 
    $_GET['ru'], 
    $_GET['es'], 
    $_GET['br'], 
    $_GET['la'], 
    $_GET['us'], 
    $_GET['au']
  ) = explode( '/', $_GET['params']);
```

Comment: Was just about to reply to @faa that I'd try compressing the parameters and using php's `explode()`, turns out that *is* the solution. Thanks!